# BxSlider small screen infinite loop issue

Tags: jquery, bxslider

i have an issue with BxSlider that seems to only affect smaller screen sizes. When i get to the 3rd slide it moves back to the first slide (but it doesnt do it in a infinite scroll way) it jumps back left and misses the 4th slide completely - at larger screens it displays expected.

my code:

```
$(function(){
           $('.product_slider').bxSlider({
                minSlides: 1,
                maxSlides: 3,
                moveSlides: 1,
                slideWidth: 460,
                pager: false,
                nextSelector: '.right-arrow',
                prevSelector: '.left-arrow',
                prevText: 'LEFT',
                nextText: 'RIGHT'

            });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="product_slider">
   <li><img alt="" src="image1.jpg"></li>
   <li><img alt="" src="image2.jpg"></li>
   <li><img alt="" src="image3.jpg"></li>
   <li><img alt="" src="image4.jpg"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="left-arrow"></li>
    <li class="right-arrow"></li>
</ul>
```

---

EDIT
i have noticed if i make minSlides: 2 then it doesn't break it just seems to be if min slides is set to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up opting for a breakpoint and reloading the slider with new options. This was a dirtier option than i was hoping for but no way around it it would seem.

so i had 2 vars with medium & above screen sizes settings and then smaller ones e.g.

```
/* Medium and Above screens */
var largeSlider = {
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 3,
    moveSlides: 1,
    slideWidth: 480,
    preloadImages: 'all',
    pager: false,
    nextSelector: '.right',
    prevSelector: '.left',
    prevText: 'Prev',
    nextText: 'Next'
}
/* Small and below screens */
var smallSlider = {
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 1,
    moveSlides: 1,
    slideWidth: 480,
    preloadImages: 'all',
    pager: false,
    infiniteLoop: false,
    hideControlOnEnd: true,
    nextSelector: '.right-arrow',
    prevSelector: '.left-arrow',
    prevText: 'Prev',
    nextText: 'Next'
}
```

then on size or orientation change i reload the slider if the width of the screen is small using:

```
productSlider.reloadSlider(smallSlider)
```

however this had its own pitfalls because on orientation change if you get width immediately it will remember the width prior to rotation so i had to setTimeOut with 500ms

```
$(window).on('orientationchange resize', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        var screenWidth = $(window).width();

        if(screenWidth >= 600){
            var slideSetup = largeSlider;
        }
        else {
            var slideSetup = smallSlider;
        }

        //reload slider
        productSlider.reloadSlider(slideSetup);

    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem, and thanks to your note that it breaks when `minSlides: 1`, I just solved this by not using the carousel when on mobile.

I'm testing for mobile in PHP, but if you're concerned about the window being resized, you could check the window width with jQuery, and reload the slider when it hits the breaking point with the carousel options omitted. Here's the bxSlider example on passing options to the `reloadSlider` method http://bxslider.com/examples/reload-slider-settings.

Comment: HI Kaela i had to settle that on device width <600px i reload the bxslider with a non 'infiniteloop' on smaller devices.